# How to remove and add class on scroll JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const scrollList = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollList');


function scrollLeft() {
    scrollList.scrollLeft -= 50
}

function scrollRight() {
    scrollList.scrollLeft += 50
}
```

```css
#scrollList {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <button onclick="scrollLeft()">Scroll Left</button>
    <div id="scrollList">
    <p>Image</p>
    <p>Image</p>
    <p>Image</p>
    <p>Image</p>
    <p>Image</p>
    <p>Image</p>
    </div>
<button  onclick="scrollRight()">Scroll Right</button>
</div>
```

I have a Horizontal page scroll on div with arrows and I want to hide the left and right arrow when you can't scroll more. I have an gallery so when there is no more images to scroll to I want to hide the button(arrow). So in the beginning I dont want to show the left arrow, and in the end when there is no more images I want to hide the right arrow. How can I do that with javascript?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: For sure, show us your code and we can help.

Comment: Its updated with my code, its not working correctly though :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.scroll() function in JavaScript
Let xScroll=window.scrollX
Its return float value and then use conditions to show arrow
" ClassName={xScroll<70 ? 'hide' : 'show'}

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my friend. It might help you. ^_^

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add the ability to scroll */
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hide scrollbar but keep functionality</h2>
<p>Try to scroll inside the div below:</p>

<div class="example">Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. Some text to enable scrolling.. </div>

</body>
</html>
```